# BMW E90 320i 2002 is not reving up misfire

Tags: bmw, e90, 320i

My car doesn't want to rev up and is idling badly.

I have tried changing the coil packs still the same symptoms.

Comment: please guys i need your help

Comment: Probably some sort of air or fuel trim issue. Does disconnecting the MAF sensor help?

Comment: Are there any codes present? If so, what are they?

Comment: What year is the car? It can't be an E90 **and** be 2002 and the E90 320i came with a couple of different engine variants so that may affect diagnosis.

Comment: its a 2007 model 320i

Comment: The valvetronic sensor of the crankshaft